# Debug ARM processor by USB

Tags: usb, arm

I want to be able to add code to [this MCU](http://www.newark.com/jsp/search/productdetail.jsp?sku=83T7141) by connecting it to my mac by USB connection. How could I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You need a suitable JTAG interface with Mac development software. A Rowley CrossConnect with their CrossWorks software for the Mac is one solution:

http://www.rowley.co.uk/arm/index.htm

Comment: Can I get the parts from newark.com?

Comment: Mouser is their main distributor.

Comment: Is there another way to add code to the MCU from my mac without JTAG?

Comment: @Coder404 you would need a USB bootloader running on the target...

Comment: You might be able to use a USB to RS-232 converter if something like Flashmagic is available for the Mac. LPC ARM chips have a built-in RS-232 bootloader.

Comment: @LeonHeller I am reluctant to use JTAG because I want to make this device portable and function without having to be connected to computer

Comment: Why don't you try the USB to RS-232 converter, then?

Comment: @LeonHeller Is there a tutorial for it? I am new to programming ARM MCUs.

Comment: Try the NXP web site.

Comment: @LeonHeller You mean with something like this -> https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10270

Comment: A USB to TTL RS-232 would be better.

Comment: @LeonHeller I cannot find one online.

Comment: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/USB-To-RS232-TTL-CP2102-Auto-Converter-Module-Converter-Adapter-arduino-/221198810691?pt=UK_Computing_Parallel_Serial_PS_2&hash=item338079fe43

Comment: "I am reluctant to use JTAG because I want to make this device portable and function without having to be connected to computer" -> this is completely fine with JTAG, you use it for initial programming then disconnect the JTAG and the device boots from internal Flash.

Comment: @LeonHeller I think that that only ships to the UK